# Last two digits of $3^{400}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to calculate the last two digits of $3^{400}$, but working $\bmod {100}$ is proving intractable. I did the last digit case pretty handily, and now I'm stuck at last two.

Comment: If you just want to know the last two digits, you can use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E400) or Python: $3^{400} = 70550791086553325712464271575934796216507949612787315762871223209262085551582934156579298529447134158154952334825355911866929793071824566694145084454535257027960285323760313192443283334088001$. So `01` is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: Actually, in Python the `pow` function has an optional third argument, the modulo of the power.  With it you even can compute quite easily the last two digits of 3⁴⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰: pow(3, 4000000000, 100) → 1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have $3^{400}=(-1+10)^{200}$. The first term in the expansion via the Binomial Theorem is $1$. The other terms are divisible by $100$. Indeed by $1000$.

Answer (score 20):

Are you familiar with the [generalization of Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Generalizations)?

From it you know that $3^{\phi(100)}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function. I get $\phi(100)=40$, and so $3^{400}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$ if I haven't made any errors.

Comment: I have seen it before, but it was not discussed in this class, which makes me think that we are supposed to do this simply using the basics of modular arithmetic?

Comment: @jmi4 A way to force your way through it would be to compute lower powers of $3$ until you find something easy to work with. Investigating the first few powers shows $3^{20}=3486784401$, so $3^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$ and the rest follows.

Comment: I think this is what we have to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also the reason 20 works even though $\varphi{(100)} = 40$ is because $\lambda{(100)} = 20$ (ref. Carmichael function).

Answer (score 13):

$$3^{400}=3^{5\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 20}\equiv 43^{2\cdot 2\cdot 20}\equiv 49^{2\cdot 20} \equiv 1^{20} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod 100) $$

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, just happened to see this after comign over from StackOverflow, so here's a more algorithmic approach, since that's what I'm good at...

Since you only need the last two digits, you can keep truncating the left side of any results you get along the way, since they will stop contributing the value of the last two digits with each multiplication.

So, you can times 3 by itself 400 times, and after each time, ignore the 100's column and greater. Since it's 3, the last number wil only ever be 1,3,9 or 7, so we can always safely do so.

Easy to code (coming from a programmer), but I've got no idea how to put that into a mathematical formula.

Comment: +1, even better: The last digits establish a periodicity. As you said, the last digits will always be 1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7,... (corresponding to $3^0,3^1,3^2,...$) with a period of four, so the final digit of $3^{400}$ is again $1$. The second-to-last digits has a sequence 0,0,0,2,8,4,2,8,6,8,4,4,4,2,6,0,2,6,8,6,0,0,0,2,... with a period of 16, which also divides $400=25\cdot16$, so the second-to-last digit is zero. And since the third-to-last digits sequence will have a periodicity that is an even multiple of 16 (I'm not sure it is definitely $16^2=256$ though), that digit is less easy...

Comment: This is called modulo 100 arithmetic, for what it's worth.

Comment: The OP has tried this though as he mentions.

Comment: This is in VBA: `Function x(Pow, Mult, Modulo)` ¶
`Dim q: x = 1: For q = 1 To Pow:  x = x * Mult Mod Modulo: Next` ¶
`End Function` - I can't put newlines in a comment, so split it at the ¶ symbol

Answer (score 1):

Expanding 3^400 binominally as (1+2)^400
It comes out to be 1+800k where k is a positive rational integer.  Therefore last two terms are 01 and last three equals 001.
Hope you understood

Comment: Please utilize MathJax/LaTeX markup to improve readability, and perhaps explain what 'binomially' means, since others in the future or even the OP themself will benefit from full details.