# Finding the last two digits of $3^{400}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Find the last two digits of the decimal representation of $3^{400}$.

This exercise Is under the Euler's theorem and Fermat's little theorem section of the worksheet so I think that we are supposed to use those to solve this. My problem is that this is the first time I'm seeing an exercise of this kind and I don't know how to proceed. Can someone give me a tip on how to do this or show me how it's done?

Comment: The last two digits are the same thing as the integer reduced mod 100.

Comment: [An exact duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194482/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple application of the totient theorem.

Applying it we get that

$$3^{\phi(100)}\equiv 1\pmod {100} $$ i.e.

$$3^{40}\equiv 1\pmod {100} $$

That's because $GCD(3, 100) = 1$ so we can apply the theorem.

Going on from there is pretty much easy.

Just raise the last congruence to the power of $10$ and you get

$$3^{400}\equiv 1\pmod {100} $$

So the last two digits are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: What you've applied here is the totient theorem, not Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, sorry. I know it as Euler's theorem actually.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use binomial expansion:

$3^{400}=(10-1)^{200}\equiv-200\times10+1\equiv1\bmod100$

(in fact, $\bmod 1000$).

Comment: Did it occur to you that this might have been asked before? Twice, in fact (ignoring the countless near duplicate that can be solved with the same tools).